# Building restartless Firefox extension with Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the latest version from Firefox Addon SDK (https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk) to build my extension. Additionally I am using Erik Vold's toolbarbutton package (https://github.com/erikvold/toolbarbutton-jplib) to display the extension button in the top toolbar. When running `cfx xpi` and installing the extension it tells me everything went fine (no restart or whatsoever required) but the toolbar button only shows up when I am actually restarting the browser.

How can I make it really restartless?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `moveTo` function to force insert the toolbar button on install.  I believe it's a bug in the code but I haven't asked Erik about it.

Something like this will work:

```
var ToolbarButton = require('toolbarbutton').ToolbarButton;
var tbb = ToolbarButton(options);
tbb.moveTo(options);
```